# how insert layer in pretrained model

Tags: keras, insert, layer, pre-trained-model

I recently wanted to insert a self-attention mechanism after each convolutional layer in a pretrained ResNet50. However, I encountered some issues, and I wrote a simple code to reproduce this error. In this code, I attempted to insert Dropout into the first convolutional layer of the pretrained ResNet50.

Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.applications import ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Reshape, multiply, Input, Dropout, Lambda
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

inputs = Input((224, 224, 3))
inputss = Lambda(tf.keras.applications.resnet50.preprocess_input)(inputs)
base_model = ResNet50(input_tensor=inputss, weights='imagenet')

layer_names = [layer.name for layer in base_model.layers]
out1_index = layer_names.index('conv1_conv')
layer = model.layers[out1_index]

layer = Dropout(0.2)(layer.output)

nextlay = model.layers[out1_index+1]
nextlay.input = layer

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=base_model.output)
model.summary()
```

Here is the error message:
AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last)
D:\ANACONDA\envs\tensorflow-keras-gpu2.5.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py in setattr(self, name, value)
2742 try:
-> 2743 super(tracking.AutoTrackable, self).setattr(name, value)
2744 except AttributeError:

AttributeError: can't set attribute

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_34868\1389651317.py in 
19
20 nextlay = model.layers[out1_index+1]
---> 21 nextlay.input=layer
22
23

D:\ANACONDA\envs\tensorflow-keras-gpu2.5.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py in setattr(self, name, value)
2746 ('Can't set the attribute "{}", likely because it conflicts with '
2747 'an existing read-only @property of the object. Please choose a '
-> 2748 'different name.').format(name))
2749 return
2750

AttributeError: Can't set the attribute "input", likely because it conflicts with an existing read-only @property of the object. Please choose a different name.

Is there any other way to achieve my desired goal?``

I expect the features after Dropout to be inputted into the layers following conv1_conv. This way, I can insert Dropout into the pretrained ResNet50.